# How to include count and sum query sets for models & views

Tags: django-models, django-views

I am trying to add up the number of tickets (count) and the (sum) of the price of each ticket purchased. The ticket is a fixed price of $25 each. I've used this in my models.py:

```python
class Ticket(models.Model):
   venue=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   quantity=models.IntegerField(null=True)
   price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
   loop=models.BooleanField(default=True)
   purchaser = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="purchases", 
   on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I am confused where to do the query sets to get the total number of tickets and the summation of the prices? Would it be

```python
total_price=Ticket.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('price'))
ticket_count = Tickets.objects.count()
```

Would the above variables (ex: total_price and _ticket_count) be included as columns in the models or it needs to be stated only in the views? Can quantity be the same as count? Thank you very, very much!

Comment: I think you're storing number of tickets purchased by a user in quantity ?

Comment: Hi Atul, that is correct. I wanted to store the number or in this case the "quantity" of tickets times the fixed price of $25. I also wanted to see if I can add taxes to it. I tried adding a field of taxes as 0.0725. Can you please advise on how to go about querying it? I added: @property
        def total(self):
        q= self.price * self.quantity
        t= q *0.0725
        totalPrice= t + self.price
        return totalPrice                           under Ticket model but to no avail. Thank you for your response, your feedback would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[More on aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
from django.db.models import Sum

# This will give total tickets sold to all the user 
total_tickets = Ticket.objects.aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
total_cost = total_tickets * 25
```

Comment: Thank you Atul for your response. Is that supposed to be included right below the Ticket model or views? I tried to do that and it didn't go through. I tried this query: "total":Ticket.objects.filter(purchaser=User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])).aggregate(total_cost=Sum(F('price')*F('quantity'), output_field=FloatField()) in views.py but it's invalid synthax. FYI, I included--default=25.00 in the price field--would these be correct? Thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: In views, you need to do this.